# Set of Units of Continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am asked to find set of units, $R^{\times}$, of a ring of continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ denoted as $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, unit is $a \in R$ such that $ab = 1$ for some $b \in R$. Are these just the inverses of all the functions? I am having a hard time trying to grasp the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hint to get started: Try to figure out whether or not the function $f(x) = x + 2$ is a unit in $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I would say no because $1/(x+2)$ is not a continuous function. Then, I suppose that all functions that can take on the value 0 will not be a unit since the inverse would be undefined at a point that makes it 0. So would it be just constant functions $\neq 0$?

Comment: You are on the right track, but the functions need not be constant.  See my answer.

Comment: Next question: is $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ a unit in $C(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a necessary condition for $f(x) \in C(\Bbb R)$ to have a multiplicative inverse $g(x) \in C(\Bbb R)$ is that

$f(x)g(x) = 1, \; \forall x \in \Bbb R; \tag 1$

this in turn implies

$f(x) \ne 0, \; \forall x \in \Bbb R; \tag 2$

indeed, if (2) failed there would be $y \in \Bbb R$ with

$1 = f(y)g(y) = 0 \cdot g(y) = 0, \; \Longrightarrow \Longleftarrow; \tag 3$

so we see (2) must hold if (1) does; in fact, (2) is  sufficient for $f(x) \in R^\times$, since then the function

$g(x) = (f(x))^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{f(x)} \in C(\Bbb R) = R^\times; \tag 4$

in short, the inverses $R^\times$ are the reciprocals of the *non-vanishing* functions; but if

$\exists y \in \Bbb R, \; f(y) = 0, \tag 5$

then $f(x)$ is *not* possessed of a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: More simply, the units $R^\times$ are the non-vanishing functions.

Comment: @lhf:  what I said, but more tersely worded! :)